# How to show data from multiple section in codeigniter?

Tags: database, view, codeigniter-3

How to call dynamic data from model in single page in multiple section, from different tables, without using join in `codeigniter`?

Comment: You can get your data updated in JSON data and then later you can use it without a database.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this one help you :-

```
public function index()
    {
        $this->load->model('modal_1');
        $this->load->model('modal_2');
        $this->load->model('modal_3');
        $data['modal_data1']=$this->modal_1->function_name();
        $data['modal_data2']=$this->modal_2->function_name();
        $data['modal_data3']=$this->modal_3->function_name();
         ////PRINT RECORDS/////
        print_r($data);
        ////////GET RECORDS IN VIEW PAGE/////
       //$this->load->view('home_page',$data);
    }
```